# What is this red little cocoon like creature here?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this bug here outdoor on the wall of my backyard. I’m in California.

Red and looks like a cocoon, notice some tiny dots on its back. About 1cm.
Does anyone know what kind of insect is this? Seen it there for a few days now.

Thanks[image]

Comment: _"Seen it there for a few days now"_ On the exact same spot or was it moving?

Comment: On the exact same spot!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a lady beetle pupa.  Given the appearance and your description of it's size, my guess would be of *Harmonia axyridis*.

Here'a link, with a picture of another pupa about half way down the page: https://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/publication/in361. This species has a diversity of colorations, both on the adults and the pupa.

Here's an example of another pupa of what is most likely the same species (from https://bugguide.net/node/view/410817/bgimage):
[image]